# Populate Select2 from JSON Ajax Response

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, jquery-select2

I am trying to populate a select2 input box from a php/mysql query using ajax.

Here's my code:

```
 var groups_array = [];

    $.getJSON('ajax_get_json.php?what=contact_groups', function (data) {

        $.each(data, function (index) {
            groups_array.push({
                id: data[index].value,
                text: data[index].text
            });
        });

    });

$("#contact_groups_select").val(groups_array);
```

contact_groups_select is the ID of my select2 input.

My JSON ajax response looks like this:

```
 [{"value":"12","text":"Brodheadsville"}]
```

My select2 is not populating though.  I hope I supplied enough code to get some help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

rather than using `.val()` you should be using the select2 method

```
$('#contact_groups_select').select2({data: groups_array});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reponse, but that doesn't populate it either.

Comment: have you logged the value of `groups_array` to make sure it's valid?

Comment: $('#contact_groups_select').val(12)  does populate one of the options. That's why I used .val.

Comment: Hmm.....  I just did console.log(groups_array); after the .getJSON and there's no data in there!

Comment: I still think `select2` is the right method to use, they could very likely be calling `.val` under the covers but we don't know what else they might be doing to update the object/data

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `groups_array` is not populated until the callback of getJSON() method which asynchronous.

So, you should put your code inside the callback function:

```
var groups_array = [];

$.getJSON('ajax_get_json.php?what=contact_groups', function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index) {
        groups_array.push({
            id: data[index].value,
            text: data[index].text
        });
    });
    // Call val() or select2() method here
    $("#contact_groups_select").val(groups_array);
});
```

Comment: Thanks all.  I think you are right, Chitrang, but that code isn't working either to populate.  I think I need to address the array.  If I do console.log of the array there's nothing logged.  If I try to alert(data[index].value) within the .each function, each id does show in alert boxes.

Comment: Let me rephrase... if I use your code and log the array within getJSON the array is showing!